# find the Jordan form of A?1

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be the complex matrix

Let $$A =\begin{bmatrix} 2&0&0&0&0&0 \\1&2&0&0&0&0\\-1 &0&2&0&0&0\\0&1&0&2&0&0\\1&1&1&1&2&0\\0&0&0&0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

Now find the  Jordan  form of A?

My attempt  is  the characteristic polynomial of $A$  =$( λ-2)^5$$(λ +1)$ and minimal polynomial  is $(λ+1) (λ-2)^2$....after that  I am not able to proceed,,,,

pliz help me....

Comment: From the minimal polynomial, you know that: for $\;\lambda=1\;$ there is no problem, and for $\;\lambda=2\;$ you know the largest Jordan block corresponding to it has size $\;2\;$... Have you already found out the corresponding eigenspace's dimension? That's all you still need

Comment: You need to find the geometric multiplicity for $\lambda=2$.

Comment: @DonAntonio  here eigen space dimension is  6

Comment: @gimusi geometric $ λ = 2$  is  5.....how  can  i find  jordan form of A??

Comment: @Stupid If geometric multiplicity of $\lambda=2$ is 5 the matrix  would be diagonalizable but that seems in contrast with the information obtained by the minimal polynomial (from which it seems that the largest jordan block has dimension 2). Revise your derivation.

Comment: @Stupid That is impossible, as **the whole space's dimension** is $\;6\;$ ...

Comment: The algebraic multiplicity of $λ=2$ is 5, but the geometric multiplicity is the dimension of the eigenspace of $λ=2$, which I haven't checked but am guessing is less than 5. Otherwise the jordan form would be a diagonal matrix.

Comment: the minimal polynomial is actually $(x-2)^4 (x+1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the given info about the characteristic and minimal polynomials, your options for JCF of that matrix are:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2&1&0&0&0&0 \\0&2&0&0&0&0\\0 &0&2&0&0&0\\0&0&0&2&0&0\\0&0&0&0&2&0\\0&0&0&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix} 2&1&0&0&0&0 \\0&2&0&0&0&0\\0 &0&2&1&0&0\\0&0&0&2&0&0\\0&0&0&0&2&0\\0&0&0&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

The first one: one block of size $2$, three of size $1$, and the second option is two blocks each of size $2$, one of size $\;1\;$ . These are the unique possible JCF's, up to order of blocks,for your matrix with the given info.

If you **already** calculate the dimension of the eigenspace $\;V_2\;$ corresponding to $\;\lambda=2\;$, thenL the first case above is for $\;\dim V_2=4\;$ , and the second case for $\;\dim V_2=3\;$

Comment: one more doubt@DonAntonio,,,as  in the third row  of 2nd matrix(rightside)..  why u write 0 0 2 1 0 0  ??  i thinks  it should  be   0 0 2 0  0 0?

Comment: @Stupid The right side is the one with **two** Jordan blocks of size two each, otherwise it'd be identical with the first matrix.

Comment: The minimal polynomial is actually $(x-2)^4 (x+1)$

Answer (score 2):

You have to consider the sequence of subspaces:
$$\{0\}\subset\ker(A-2I)\subset\ker(A-2I)^2\subset\ker(A-2I)^3\subset\dots$$
and the corresponding sequence of their dimensions,  $\;0\le d_1\le d_2\le d_3\le\dots$

These sequences are strictly increasing to begin with, then stabilise. A fundamental result is this:

> With the above notations, for each $k\ge 1$, the number $n_k$ of Jordan blocks of size $\ge k$ is 
>   $$n_k=d_k-d_{k-1}.$$

*Edit*: 
This procedure is also the starting point to determine a *Jordan basis*.

Comment: thanks  a  Bernards    but what is d  ?? is  its  dimesnion of kernel ?

Comment: @Stupid: The $d_k$s are the dimensions of the so-called ‘iterated kernels’, $\ker(A-\lambda I)^k$ (with $d_0=0$). This $d_1$ is the dimension of the eigenspace $E_\lambda$.

Comment: thanks  a  lots @bernard

Comment: the minimal polynomial is actually $(x-2)^4 (x+1)$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{1}{81}
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 10&6&9&9&-27&81 \\
 -108&-81&-81&0&0&0 \\
 -38&-39&-18&-18&-27&0 \\
 -48&-45&-27&-27&0&0 \\
 -18&-27&0&0&0&0 \\
 -27&0&0&0&0&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 2&0&0&0&0&0 \\
 1&2&0&0&0&0 \\
 -1&0&2&0&0&0 \\
 0&1&0&2&0&0 \\
 1&1&1&1&2&0 \\
 0&0&0&0&1&-1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 0&0&0&0&0&-3 \\
 0&0&0&0&-3&2 \\
 0&-1&0&0&3&2 \\
 0&1&0&-3&2&0 \\
 0&0&-3&2&1&0 \\
 1&0&-1&1&0&0 \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 -1&0&0&0&0&0 \\
 0&2&0&0&0&0 \\
 0&0&2&1&0&0 \\
 0&0&0&2&1&0 \\
 0&0&0&0&2&1 \\
 0&0&0&0&0&2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$